# how can i pass a ArrayList of Model to other fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

i have a model and in my model there is some value (Title : String ) (Price : String ) (image : Int ) ...

i'm used live data and i could that pass a string to other fragment / it want to know how pass a ArrayList of My Model to other fragmetn with livedata? ... there is Something else beter ? i use kotlin in android

i tried to pass a string to my other fragment and it worked

fragmetn1 : Fragment

inflater(R.id.fragmetn1 , conatiner , false )

fragmetn 2 : Fragment

inflater(R.id.fragmetn2 , conatiner , false )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass ModelData to fragment the you can use pass thorugh **newInstance()** function of fragment.

Here is the implementation example

Call this in activity/fragment from where you wanted to pass data.

```
FragmentName.newInstance(ModelData)
```

Create this function in that fragment where you want to get data.

```
 fun newInstance(modelData: ModelData?) = FragmentName().apply {
           var arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putParcelable("testing", modelData)
            }
```

Comment: thank you for yout answer body ... i want pass data from LiveData Class to my other fragment ...